# HTML - how to insert a form in the subsequent page?

Tags: html, forms

Suppose I have something like this:

```
<form method=get action="token.php">
<b>Enter token:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="token"><BR>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And after the user enters the token, he is taken to a new page that displays the results of running token.php. How do I edit this new page? What if I want to enter another form in it?

I am just learning these things(complete beginner).

Thank you very much

P.S. Can I add something like this in the middle of the .php file?

```
<html>
<form method=get action="myPhp.php">
<b>Enter data:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="data"><BR>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

What would the correct syntax look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two major ways to add HTML code to your PHP file.

First things first: All PHP code has to go in between `<?php` and `?>`. After a `?>` and before a `<?php`, you can write HTML code which will then be outputted without going through any PHP code.

Another way to output HTML is by simply using `echo` in PHP.

```
echo "<b>Hello world!</b>";
```

That line of code will print a bold "Hello world!" message on your page.

Anyway, with all due respect, I think I can tell from your question that you do not fully grasp the concept of PHP and HTML just yet. Before trying to use PHP I recommend you try to do some PHP tutorials -- it's a whole other language than HTML, and knowing HTML does not mean you'll be able to work with PHP right away.

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting your form to `token.php`.  The server will parse this and return the result.  Hence if you want to modify the result of the form action you'll need to modify `token.php` to include the form you want.

Comment: How? Can you please give me an example? Because I know how to create forms in html, but how can that be done in php code?

Comment: You'll need to learn PHP.  This means opening up `token.php` in a text editor and changing it.  Any problems you come across can be either googled - or asked on here.

Comment: I made some edits in the original question about how I tried it.